# SSIS - Suggest types from destination

Tags: sql, ssis

Is there a way to get SSIS (<cough>hateit</cough>) to suggest the types on a flat file connection mgr from a destination table?

So the problem is I have a largish table with lots of text fields and even when using suggest types, it will sometimes set the length of those fields smaller than the target column.  That, of course, would be fine for the current set of data, but if I expect to use this package again on a different file in the future that may have more data in this particular field, then I have myself a problem.

Yes, I can go through and set them all manually (<cough>sucks</cough>), but I'm hoping I'm missing a feature somewhere where I can say, "Define this here file in terms of that there table".

Ideas?  Thoughts?  Rants about SSIS?

Comment: What kind of flat-file do you use?

Comment: The good news is, I did this just yesterday. The bad news is, I have no friggin' idea how I did it. I'll try to duplicate it and post the steps, but no promises.

Comment: This particular flat file is just a tab delimited ASCII format file.  We've also tried the unicode format - neither seems to make this suck less.

Comment: Tom - I look forward to your thoughts.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reconfigure the column information on a flat file connection manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983403/how-to-reconfigure-the-column-information-on-a-flat-file-connection-manager)

Answer (score -2):

You should also try to set your fields with the advanced properties(right click datasource)

Comment: he needs an automated way